# Alternative to rich:extendedDataTable in PrimeFaces 6.1

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, richfaces, primefaces-datatable

We are currently migrating our application which was written in richfaces to primefaces.

I am looking for alternative for rich:extendedDataTable in primefaces. the extended data table does something like this [image: rich extendedDatatable]

is there a way to achiveve this in primefaces with p:dataTable?

Comment: Did you try? I don't see anything in the image that cannot be done using a `p:dataTable`.

Comment: Yes i gave it for a try. There are currently no options in primefaces as of now which can supplement rich:extendedDatatable.

Answer (score 0):

From looking over the RichFaces ExtendedDatatable I think the [PrimeFaces Extensions Sheet](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/sheet/basicUsage.jsf) component is what you are looking for. From what I can see it does almost everything that Extended Datatable does except Live Scroll.

Comment: Let me check this out.